# List all values existing of a property?

Tags: mongodb, database

Assume I have a `Student` collection:

```
{
    name: "ABC",
    age: 10,
    address {
        city: "CITY1",
        state: "STATE",
    }
}

{
    name: "DEF",
    age: 11,
    address {
        city: "CITY2",
        state: "STATE",
    }
}

{
    name: "ABC",
    age: 12,
    address {
        city: "CITY1",
        state: "STATE",
    }
}
```

Can I get the list of all unique `City` values from the list? For example, with the above 3 documents, I would like to get the list `{"CITY1", "CITY2"}`

I was just getting started with MongoDB from Relational Database, so this is a little confused for me, since I needed another Address table for it and I can just use `SELECT DISTINCT` to get what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB has a similar [db.collection.distinct()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) command.

To access elements in the `address` subdocument you need to use [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation), so the complete query would be:

```
 db.Student.distinct("address.city")
```

Some helpful documentation links to help you make the translation from SQL queries:

- [SQL to MongoDB Mapping Chart](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/)
- [SQL to Aggregation Mapping Chart](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/)

Answer (score 0):

Just for notes, there is already [distinct](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) as mentioned, but for a more conventional response, use [aggregate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/):

```js
db.Student.aggregate([
    {"$unwind": "$address" }},
    {"$group": { "_id": "$address.city" }},
    {"$project": { "_id": 0, "city" : "$_id" }}
])
```

Long winded compared to distinct, but it depends on what your eyes want.